# postgresql update column from select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to update a column from one table with a select query.

It runs and updates the entire `type_` column as `religious` (text field).

I am trying to only update the rows where the religious geometry intersects the parcel geometry.

```
update wash_parcels_final
set    type_ = t.religious 
from   (select wash_worship.religious 
        from   wash_parcels_final 
        join   wash_worship 
        on     st_intersects(wash_worship.geom, wash_parcels_final.geom)) t
```

Comment: What is `t.religious` in that query? Without that part, it might work, though `type_` seems like a strange choice for a column name.

Comment: t.religious is a text

Comment: so add where geometry_intersects to the end?..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
update wash_parcels_final
    set type_ = ww.religious 
    from wash_worship ww  
    where st_intersects(ww.geom, wash_parcels_final.geom);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Use PgAdmin4 and last version of PostgreSQL and this query works for me:

```
update public."UserPoints"
set "AvailablePoints" = up."AvailablePoints" + tc."CLV"
from public."UserPoints" up join public."TEMPCLV" tc on up."UserId" = tc."CUSTOMER_NUMBER"
```

Hope help someone else!